# AVAudioPlayer crashes my app with EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1) when running multiple sounds at once

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, multi-touch

Hello my sounds play but if I keep hitting multiple sounds rapidly I    get a crash EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1).  Been trying for a long time to figure this one out.  I tried using properties as well but no luck. Anybody ever seen this happen when playing multiple simultaneous sounds?

```
@interface SoundBoardScene : SKScene<AVAudioPlayerDelegate> 
AVAudioPlayer  *Player1;
AVAudioPlayer *Player2;
AVAudioPlayer *Player3;
AVAudioPlayer *Player4;
AVAudioPlayer *Player5;
AVAudioPlayer *Player6;
AVAudioPlayer *Player7;
AVAudioPlayer *Player8;

-(AVAudioPlayer*) PlayAudioFile:(AVAudioPlayer*)player withAudioFileName:(NSString*)audioFileName withExtensionType:  (NSString*)audioFileExtension withLoopCount:(uint)NumberOfLoops

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                     pathForResource:audioFileName
                                     ofType:audioFileExtension]];
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
player.numberOfLoops = NumberOfLoops;
return player;
```

}

```
-(void) initSounds

Player1 = [animalObject PlayAudioFile:Player1 withAudioFileName:@"Sound1" withExtensionType:@"mp3" withLoopCount:0];
 Player1.delegate=self;
Player2 = [animalObject PlayAudioFile:Player2 withAudioFileName:@"Sound2" withExtensionType:@"mp3" withLoopCount:0];
Player2.delegate=self;

etc
etc
```

}

```
if([node.name isEqualToString:@"Sound1"])
    {

            [Player1 play];

    }
if([node.name isEqualToString:@"Sound2"])
    {

            [Player2 play];

    }
```

Comment: Add a exception breakpoint and check which line is causing the crash

Comment: self.scene.view.paused = YES; by this you can pause current scene when switch to other

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to use avplayer for play sound file.

try this code

```
[self runAction:[SKAction repeatAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"pew1.wav" waitForCompletion:NO] count:count]];
```

Comment: Need to be able to stop the sounds as well as play the same sound only once until finished but different sounds at anytime as long as they aren't currently playing.

Comment: This way also crashes with users hitting multiple sounds quickly

Comment: @EricMeans 1st remove all avplayer objects and then try to play sound in queue that will help a lot in crash issue

Comment: Requirements are: play multiple sounds at once anytime they are tapped. If a certain sound is playing don't play that same sound again until that sound finishes then you can tap the button to play again. Be able to stop all sounds at any point.

Comment: @EricMeans try this link for multiple sound http://iknowsomething.com/ios-sdk-spritekit-sound/

Comment: @EricMeans  Did you solve this issue .. I also face this bug ,My Avplayer get crash .. How  to you solve this